# Error: No label found for checkboxradio widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am getting this error:

> No label found for checkboxradio widget

Please can you help. This is new for me and I am using jquery-1.12.4.js

```html
<div class="sign-radio-button-align" id="showSignDiv">
  <s:iterator id="row" value="filePaths">
    <div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-11"></div>
      <s:radio name="images" value="row" list="row" />
    </div>
  </s:iterator>
</div>
```

```js
$("input:radio").checkboxradio();
```

Comment: This probably means your radio inputs need to have associated `<label>`'s.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your HTML Code does not appear to include a `<input>` element. I also do not see the associated `<label>` element. Please review: http://jqueryui.com/checkboxradio/